# No relative elements - What happens?

Tags: html, css, css-position, viewport

*Hello,
So I bumped into quite an interesting problem today. I am not sure I got it right, nor am I sure what is actually happening in the background. I did not find any article answering my question. So here it is :*

Let's say I have a page very very simple, something like:

```
<html style="height:100%;">
  <body style="height:100%;">
    <div style="height:2000px;"></div>
    <test style="position:absolute; bottom:0;"></test>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I did not set any element as relative.

**What I was expecting** : 
My test should be positioned relatively to the body element. So at the very end of my page.

**What seemed to happen**: My div was positioned relatively to the viewport (???) 
So instead of being at the very end of the page. it was Xpx from the top.
so if Im on a browser with 900px height, then the element is positioned 900px from the top, and stays there if I scroll.

So sorry if this aint clear. I can specify if needed. Any explanation ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: yeah of course, the easy solution is to set the html or body to relative. I was more interested in understand the theory behind this. but yeah. all good.

Answer (score 0):

An absolutely positioned element will be positioned in terms of the nearest relatively positioned ancestor in the flow. Make sure one of the parent wrappers has position set to relative.

In this fiddle the element is at the bottom:
http://jsfiddle.net/L51u8qhz/

```
<div class="html" style="height:100%;">
  <div class="body" style="height:100%; position: relative;">
    <div style="height:2000px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; background: #000; height: 10px; width: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)

*The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the **initial container** is used.*
Now, the **initial container** is the box of the size of viewport. It will not move even when you scroll.
So, if there is no containing block for the absolute positioned element, then position will be w.r.t the region bounded by the viewport.
Recommended solution is to set position to a parent (mostly it's body) other than static(mostly it's relative)

Comment: Well yeah that's the thing. I believe my element is positionnent relatively to that "box the size of the viewport". But if scroll, it does scroll. 
I know the solution here is ofc to use relative positioning. but I found this interesting as we rarely use absolute positioning without relative parents.